# Calling ActiveRecord relationship with polymorphic model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, activerecord

I'm trying to create a rake task that retrieves data from an API. However the data that I need has data from different models.

Here is my error:

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Precision Agriculture",
    "topics_owners_ids": "#<User::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x000000095fa498>",
    "keywords_list": null,
    "keywords": [

    ],
    "organizations_list": null,
    "organizations": [

    ],
    "social_groups_list": null,
    "feeds_list": null,
    "articles_list": null,
    "people": null
  }
```

]

Here is my rake task:

```
namespace :fieldfacts do
  desc "Export Topics"
  task :export_topics => :environment do
    out = []
    File.open("public/topics.json","w") do |f|
      Topic.all.each do |topic|
          api = TopicsService.new()
          topic_api = api.get(topic.topic_api_id)
          out << {
             'id' => topic.id,
             'name' => topic.name,
             'topics_owners_ids' => topic.users.id,
             'keywords_list' => topic_api.keywords_list,
             'keywords' => topic_api.keywords,
             'organizations_list' => topic_api.organizations_list,
             'organizations' => topic_api.organizations,
             'social_groups_list' => topic_api.social_groups_list,
             'feeds_list' => topic_api.feeds_list,
             'articles_list' => topic_api.articles_list,
             'people' => topic_api.people
          }
      end
      f.write(JSON.pretty_generate(out))
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, the topics_owners_ids is not returning the correct data. I'm not sure how to fetch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`topic.users` will give you the collection object and you need to select ids. Try
`topic.users.pluck(:id)`

Comment: I think it works, although every id is 1 and i'm not sure how to check whether that is correct or not.

Comment: Maybe all your topics are associated with same user. You can check that in your database. Also, if you need just unique ids then you can use `topic.users.pluck(:id).compact.uniq`. This will also get rid of nil.